# How to configure rules at application instance level in PCF Auto Scalar?

Tags: cloud, cloud-foundry, autoscaling

I have configured Auto Scalar rules with Container Memory threshold min 30% and max 70%. When the application is getting used the requests are going to instances in round robin fashion. So when the first instance is reaching its threshold but auto scalar will not create new instance ; because it create new instance based on the average.

As #1 instance, reached its limit ; the instance is crashing and the requests to that instance are failing .

Can we configure rules at instance level also?

Answer (score 0):

This applies to PCF Auto Scaler (not the OSS Cloud Foundry project by the same name).

Memory and CPU-based autoscaling with PCF Auto Scaler are very difficult to get configured correctly and don't often behave the way users expect. I believe what you're experiencing here is part of that. What also makes it tricky is that some application runtimes will do their own memory management separate from the OS. So from the OS's point-of-view, which is the metric used to auto scale, it looks like you're using more memory than actually being used, which can scale up prematurely and possibly prevent scale down where it should happen.

My suggestion would be that you try to autoscale off of metrics that represent your actual goals, not the state of the system. If you have a web application, using latency-based auto scaling rules makes a lot of sense. You can configure your auto scaling rules so that you can meet the latency service objectives set for your application.

You can use HTTP throughput-based scaling as well, although there is a critical performance bug in older versions of autoscaler, so [check here to make sure you're patched for that](https://community.pivotal.io/s/article/autoscaling-using-http-throughput-latency-metrics?language=en_US).

If neither of those will work, then I would suggest scaling off of custom metrics. You can export something that is meaningful to your application, like how much work it's handling (jobs processed per second) or whatever makes sense for your application.